Writing In a Predefined word document using angular, docxtemplater,pizzip,file-saver
I want to manipulate a .docx file using angular.
I wrote a program and implemented the docxtemplater, but in the .docx it is writing undefined.
This is the final output of file.docx
My name is undefined
my address is undefined
My email address is undefined
expected out
My name is Developer
my address is India
My email address is developer2@gmail.com
template :- docx
My name is {data.name}
my address is {data.address}
My email address is {data.email}
My code :


In order to use the dotted syntax, {data.name}, ..., you need to enable the angular parser :
You can do so like this :
import Docxtemplater from "docxtemplater";
import PizZip from "pizzip";
import expressionParser from "docxtemplater/expressions.js";

expressionParser.filters.upper = function (input) {
    // Make sure that if your input is undefined, your
    // output will be undefined as well and will not
    // throw an error
    if (!input) return input;
    return input.toUpperCase();
};

const zip = new PizZip(content);

const doc = new Docxtemplater(zip, {
    paragraphLoop: true,
    linebreaks: true,
    parser: expressionParser
});
doc.render({
   first_name: "John",
   last_name: "Doe",
   phone: "0652455478",
   description: "New Website",
});

See here for the documentation about the angular parser :
https://docxtemplater.com/docs/angular-parse/
